# Unknown token 'year' when trying to exctract year from date

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I get an error stating

> Token unknown - line 2, column 51.
>   year.

when trying to execute the following snippet (second date would be a variable, not hard-coded) that compares years of entries:

```
SELECT * FROM list_users
WHERE ((extract(year from dt_create)) = (exctract(year from cast('01.01.2016' as date))))
```

I obviously tried to wrap it all in brackets and cast to date, but the issue is that firebird doesn't recognize `year`. I don't want to settle with string comparison, so I'm going to try and find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in the `extract` part, which was written `exCtract` which left unnoticed due to firebird pointing at `year` part being an error.

Comment: Tip: when you get a token unknown in Firebird, then also check what is immediately in front of that token. The error means that the parser came across something it could no longer interpret. This could mean something is wrong with the current token, or that the previously parsed token(s) led it down the wrong path.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, I mostly work with C++ and not entirely acquainted with nuances of db and Firebird in particular. Thanks.